# Indexing fails once the Hashtable object assign to same Enumeration object

Tags: java, loops, enumeration

I have following code snippet in my legacy code. Here, It is iterating two Hashtables using Enumeration.

```
Hashtable h4 = new Hashtable();
Hashtable h5 = new Hashtable();

for (int i=0 ; i < 3; i++) {
    h4.put (i, "" + i);
    //System.out.println(h4.get(i));
}

for (int i=0 ; i < 3; i++) {
    h5.put (i, "++"+i);
    //System.out.println(h5.get(i));
}

Enumeration e = h4.keys();
while (e.hasMoreElements ()) {
    System.out.println(e.nextElement());
}

e = h5.keys ();
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println(e.nextElement());
}
```

The ideal expectation as follows;

0
1
2
++0
++1
++2

However, above code print as;

2
1
0
2
1
0

Problem, I can see here is that Enumeration does not reset when it comes to loop the second Hashtable. I would like get reason for this kinds of behavior. Yes, of course, recent version of Java has more efficient ways of looping.

Answer (score 0):

you are printing only keys of hashtable not values

```
    Hashtable h4 = new Hashtable();
    Hashtable h5 = new Hashtable();

    for (int i=0 ; i < 3; i++) {
        h4.put (i, "" + i);
        //System.out.println(h4.get(i));
    }

    for (int i=0 ; i < 3; i++) {
        h5.put (i, "++"+i);
        //System.out.println(h5.get(i));
    }

    // java8 functionality
    //h4.values().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    //h5.values().stream().forEach(System.out::println);

    //if legacy one iterator
    Iterator enum1 = h4.values().iterator();
    while(enum1.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(enum1.next());
    }
    enum1 = h5.values().iterator();
    while(enum1.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(enum1.next());
    }
```

Comment: This part you are referring is commented, the printing part.